# how can include dotes using number type in html tag

Tags: jquery

i am creating a program that takes Ip Address from user and validate it now i want to that user just enter number in text field and nothing else and ip must be consist of dots and in number type dots does not include so how i include dots on it please guide me m very thankful to you. .

Comment: You forgot to add the relevant part of your code. We have no crystal ball.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure from your description but it sounds like you want the user to enter just numbers, and for your script to insert the dots after the fact.  If that's what you want, it's not possible, because the input would be ambiguous (if the user entered "12345" there'd be no way to know whether that was supposed to be "1.2.3.45", "12.3.4.5", "1.2.34.5", etc...)

Comment: its simple i try to explain it, you know that if the type of input field is number it cant pick dots but just numbers so  in my variable just number stored and compiler give me error so just simply my problem is dots also save in my variable i hope you understand now . .

Comment: That was still pretty much incomprehensible... you're saying my guess at what you're trying to do was correct? I think?   If so, *that won't work*, as I described earlier.  You can't capture an IP address without the dots and then try to add the dots after the fact, because there's no way to know where the dots belong.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use pattern and after user has typed validate format 
   and show error and let user change it

   pattern="^([0-9]{1,3}.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$"
2. Use jquery plugin like haven't tried

   https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/
3. Working plugin : jquery.mask

   Add in script

   ```
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.10/jquery.mask.js"></script>
   ```

   HTML code

   ```
   <label>ip:</label> <input class="ip_address" type="text" name="ip">
   ```

   js code to mask it:

   $('.ip_address').mask('0ZZ.0ZZ.0ZZ.0ZZ', { translation: { 'Z': { pattern: /[0-9]/, optional: true } } });

Comment: thanks but i have tried this i want to use number type instead of text this is the main issue